# Not able to click on materail tabs next tab using nightwatchjs

Tags: angular6, nightwatch.js

I have a material tab in my application. I am trying to automate test cases
using nightwatch.js. But I am not able to click on the next tab of my
application using nightwatch.js. I need to switch to next tab. Any help is
promoted
My material tab looks like this :

```html
<mat-tab-group
  id="detailsTab"
  [selectedIndex]="tabIndex"
  (selectedTabChange)="tabSelectionChange($event.index)"
>
  <mat-tab id="sample" [label]="card">
    <app-details *ngIf="tabIndex === 0"></app-details>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [label]="Report">
    <app-report *ngIf="tabIndex === 1"></app-report>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [label]="perf">
    <app-perf *ngIf="tabIndex === 2"></app-perf>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Nightwatch code looks like this:

```js
.waitForElementVisible('#detailsTab > .mat-tab-group:nth-child(1)',6000) 
.click('#detailsTab >.mat-tab-group:nth-child(1)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked for me:**

```
browser.waitForElementVisible('#detailsTab .mat-tab-label:nth-child(2)',6000) 
       .click('#detailsTab .mat-tab-label:nth-child(2)')
```

... where the `mat-tab-group` ID was `#detailsTab`. The HTML structure looked like a `<div>` with class name `mat-tab-labels`, having three child `<div>`s with class name as `mat-tab-labels` that looked like the headers of the tab.

So what I ended up doing was to select the `nth-child` element of the respectiv `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your selector is wrong. Have you checked it in the browser console to confirm that the element is found using $('#detailsTab > .mat-tab-group:nth-child(1)')?

Just a guess here, but this seems like it would work:

```
.waitForElementVisible('mat-tab#sample',6000) 
.click('mat-tab#sample')
```

Comment: Timed out while waiting for element <mat-tab #sample> to be present for 6000 milliseconds. - expected "visible" but got: "not found". While inspecting my html page i got the material tab as

Comment: While inspecting my material tab from html page its structure looks different so the id which was given to the <mat-tab> is not found.